# Getting #1111 - Invalid use of group function error

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I see there is an error in the last line. Can someone please tell me what is the alternative?

```
INSERT INTO month_week_qty 
(
    site_id, cat_id, cat_name, scat_id, scat_name, sscat_id, sscat_name, duration, w_m, year, sum_qty
) 
SELECT 
    c.site_id, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'month', MONTH(s.created_at), YEAR(s.created_at), ROUND( SUM( s.qty_ordered ) ) as qty 
FROM cat_products c, sku_qty_brand s
WHERE (c.product_id = s.product_id)
GROUP BY c.site_id, MONTH(s.created_at)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sum_qty = sum_qty + ROUND( SUM( s.qty_ordered ) )
```

Comment: Please add the `error` to your question as well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use aggregates in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause, but you can put your grouped aggregates in a subquery instead:

```
INSERT INTO month_week_qty 
(
    site_id, duration, w_m, year, sum_qty
) 
SELECT 
    site_id, duration, w_m, year, qty
FROM (
    SELECT 
        c.site_id, 'month' AS duration, MONTH(s.created_at) AS w_m, YEAR(s.created_at) AS year, ROUND( SUM( s.qty_ordered ) ) as qty 
    FROM cat_products c, sku_qty_brand s
    WHERE (c.product_id = s.product_id)
    GROUP BY c.site_id, MONTH(s.created_at)
) AS t
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sum_qty = sum_qty + t.qty
```

(I omitted the NULL columns for clarity.)